# How I can fetch Facebook user only public posts if he didnt allow or authenticate my Facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to pull all public posts made by any user even who didn't allow or authenticate my Facebook application using access_token of user who authenticated my application.

This is similar to :

If a user login on facebaook using their credentials and then access following page
https://facebook.com/zuck then he is able to view "Mark Zuckerberg" public posts.

I am able to fetch all posts of a user who authenticate my application using their access token. Is their any way that I can access other users public posts using application secret key or application access token.

Thanks in advance

Ansh Jain

Comment: I cant understand , what does those `other users` have to do with your application if they haven't authorized your app? And from where will you get these `other users` (their IDs I mean). 

Please re-think or re-phrase(if i misunderstood) of what of are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually I am trying to fetch only public posts of any facebook user as I mention in the example if you login to facebook and open above url (https://facebook.com/zuck) you are able to view his public posts. So if you are my application user and authenticate it then by using your access_token for the application I wish to fetch "Mark Zuckerberg" public posts similar as we can view on browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making `\GET` request to `PAGE_ID/feed`

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried that as well but Graph api didnt return all public feeds even for most of the user it return empty data[]

Comment: Could you please help me how do I get all public posts of a user.

Comment: Its the same /id/feed. Eg id : sahilmittal